# magento 2 search api response

Tags: magento2, rest-api, advanced-search

i am using the magento2 api V1/Search for getting search results.
It also returns the filter. The price filter is not coming in this.
Please advise.

http://stage.augvue.com/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=rings

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html will help u

Comment: But i want to use  V1/Search API. so that only i can get the filters with is attributes and its product count.